# How to use a subquery in the select statement of another query in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use a subquery in the select of another query:

```
subq = db.session.query(mytable).filter(mytable.col == '4').subquery('subq')
mainquery = db.session.query(subq).join(anothertable).filter(subq.id = anothertable.id).all()
```

The problem is that the "mainquery" results are read-only and I cannot change for example a specific column in them by looping over them, in other words I cannot write something like this:

```
for row in mainquery:
    row.col2 = 'newvalue'
```

The error says: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

(This is the simplified example, so merging the queries into one is not a solution)

Comment: `subq` is not actually a subquery in your example (it calls `all()` in the end). Are you perhaps looking for how to alias a subquery to entities: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#selecting-entities-from-subqueries ?

Comment: No, I know how to use subqueries, that was a typo. I updated my code.

Comment: Thought as much, but do check the link provided, I believe it to be what you're after.